# After FB API deprecation how can I create a post using Open Graph 'Article' object so that my post's image and meta-tags stay intact?

Tags: facebook-opengraph

I have been working on developing an **iOS mobile application** that allows a user to sign in using FB, create a post and allows users to share the post on their FB. Before **Facebook's API deprecation** the post on Facebook had the image I wanted to share as well as the meta-tags.

It was just **one click** and the user would be redirected to the application using deep linking.

Post deprecation many developers have started using **OpenGraph**, but while using the **Article Object** I have still run into problems.

Do I need to go through a **FB review** for using the OpenGraph actions? Has anybody been successful in getting around the API deprecation by using OpenGraph?

Comment: Do you go any new way. If so please let me know.